# usar username en user_id

Tags: php, mysql

cuando quiero buscar el perfil de un usuario mediante la url: http://localhost/personajes/user_profile.php?id=1

Pero lo que estoy intentando hacer es buscarlo desde
http://localhost/personajes/user_profile.php?id=Nombre_Apellido

Este es mi código para obtener el usuario

```
function find_user_by_id($id){
        try{
            $find_user = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `characters` WHERE characterID = ?");
            $find_user->execute([$id]);
            if($find_user->rowCount() === 1){
                return $find_user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Y aquí el código del user_profile.php

```
<?php
require 'includes/init.php';
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $user_data = $user_obj->find_user_by_id($_GET['id']);
    }

?>
```

¿Cómo puedo realizar este cambio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu función `find_user_by_id($id)` tiene una consulta a una tabla de la base de datos donde el criterio de comparación es `characterID` que es la columna en tu tabla `characters` que tiene el id.

si lo que deseas es buscar por el nombre solo debes cambiar el nombre de la columna que hace la selección del criterio  ejemplo `nombre`

pudiera quedarte así

```
$find_user = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `characters` WHERE nombre= ?");
```

debes tener en cuenta que deberías definir una nueva función y definir nuevas variables, para que tenga lógica tu código y sea fácil de leer, el ejemplo que te di es solo para que puedas usar el mismo código sin mucho cambio